# Open new database connection and query window in SSMS through C# application?

Tags: c#, ssms

I have a C# application that, when a user clicks a button, will open SQL Server Management Studio query editor with a specified server and database connection. What I would like to do is be able to have this same functionality, but with an already running instance of SSMS (not start a new process).

My code so far:

```
if (IsProcessOpen("Ssms") == false)
        {
            Process ssms = new Process();
            ssms.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio\\Ssms.exe";
            ssms.StartInfo.Arguments = "-S " + StaticVariables.Getserver + " -d " + StaticVariables.Getdatabase;
            ssms.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            //In already running SSMS process, open connection to server and database with new query window.
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far my research goes, there is no API available to interact with an existing SSMS processs.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334435/how-do-i-programmatically-open-a-new-tab-in-an-open-instance-of-sql-management-s)

You could try doing a hack involving SendKeys, but this would have a downside of not knowing the current state of the SSMS window (if it has any active windows open or anything)

If you could share the original requirement, we may look at some better alternatives.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but that would require shortcut keys. Shortcut keys could be different across users and versions, so I don't think this would work. The requirement is that my C# application executes predefined SQL code, but if a user wanted to execute custom SQL code, they would have to connect to server/database via SSMS.

Comment: Okay that's tricky. Not sure if this would fit into your application: Why not allow your application get the query and execute on his behalf? or do you want the user to get the full use out of SSMS?

Comment: I believe I would need SSMS. One example would be because we need to view estimated execution plans.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Most I can think of is: you could bring the existing SSMS application to foreground and let the user take of the rest (connecting to the server, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This problem was driving me crazy, and I finally found that when I changed from logging in as "sa" to using Windows Authentication, the problem was resolved.

Comment: How does that effect opening a tab vs a new SSMS instance via Process.start?